# Using Flutter and Dart, is this the best way to achieve this Future?

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I know that there are other ways of achieving this, but I want to use a Future via initState() to obtain a List using SharedPreferences without using await. The following illustrates what I want to achieve, and it does work. Because I have never used this pattern previously, I'm just unsure if it's the best way (without using await). Is there a better way without using await?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  SharedPreferences _prefs;
  String _sMessage1;
  String _sMessage2;
  List<String> _lsCategories;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future<void> future = _initPreferences();
    future.then((_) {
      if (_prefs != null) {
        try {
          _lsCategories = _prefs.getStringList("categories") ?? [];
          debugPrint("Categories = $_lsCategories");
          _sMessage2 = "Categories loaded OK";
        } catch (vError) {
          _sMessage2 = ("Error loading categories = $vError");
        }
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  Future<void> _initPreferences() {
    return SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      _prefs = prefs;
      _sMessage1 = "Preferences initialized OK";
    }).catchError((vError) {
      _sMessage1 = "Error initializing preferences = ${vError.toString()}";
      _sMessage2 = "Unable to load categories";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _createText(_sMessage1),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            _createText(_sMessage2),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Text _createText(String sText) {
  return Text(sText == null ? "" : sText,
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.red[500], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20));
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Future Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: "Flutter Future Test"),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use await? Accessing Shared Preferences is an asynchronous task. Maybe you should consider saving the data you need somewhere else, where it won't require using a Future/Await?

Comment: `"The following illustrates what I want to achieve, and it does work"` - so what is your problem then? if you dont want to use `await` you have to use `then` method - there is no third way...

Comment: @pskink, It wouldn't be the first time I've tried something new only to find there's a better way. Also, I couldn't find much online as an example.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is fine in terms of asynchrony. However, it's too verbose. For example, you do not need to transfer the prefs instance through state.

Another improvement could be to check whether the widget is still mounted when the `Future` is done. (If you use a `FutureBuilder`, you don't need to worry about this.)

A problem with your code is that you're setting state variables outside `setState()`. It is not guaranteed to work well that way, I swear I had old state used sometimes when I did that. You should set them within `setState()`

Here are a couple of different ways I would prefer to code it:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      if(!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        _prefs = prefs;
        _lsCategories = _prefs.getStringList("categories") ?? [];
        debugPrint("Categories = $_lsCategories");
        _sMessage2 = "Categories loaded OK";
      });
    }).catchError((vError) {
      setState(() {
        _sMessage2 = ("Error loading categories = $vError");
      });
    });
  }
```

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initPreferences();
  }

  Future<void> _initPreferences() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      try {
        _prefs = prefs;
        _lsCategories = _prefs.getStringList("categories") ?? [];
        debugPrint("Categories = $_lsCategories");
        _sMessage2 = "Categories loaded OK";
      } catch (vError) {
        _sMessage2 = ("Error loading categories = $vError");
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
AFAIK setState() causes a rebuild. AFAIK it does not require that all variables used in the rebuild be only changed within setState().
I know that there are other ways of doing this, but I specifically want to use a Future.
I have not previously encountered "mounted", I will look into that.
I don't understand this " For example, you do not need to transfer the prefs instance through state".
This is just a trivial example where I need "categories" and I need _prefs to get them prior to a build. In this example I'm then doing a setState() to display the messages.

Comment: Right, if all you want to do is to get data from prefs the beginning, you don't need to hold on to `_prefs` in your state class, just use it like my first example. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html talks about the `mounted` property and that you should make your state changes in the setState method. I can't tell exactly what's wrong with doing it outside before a setState, but I do remember having issues because of it.